# My PopUp Dialog backgound is black and text white for no reason

Tags: android, android-layout, popup, android-spinner

In my app, I have an activity called a Popup

Now My problem is that when I call the popup it appears BUT the background is black/dark grey and the text is white,

I have changed the background and text color using a Style, but this causes problems with my spinners, Hint texts, and general accents

My Hint texts in my TextFields are invisible with a white background(you can see them if the background is black/dark grey)

In my spinners, I have Search bars that are also invisible on white backgrounds same as the hint text
And other accents like lines between items in the spinner etc

also, My entire app has a white background and uses the same XML code for the spinners and text fields, etc. And I am only running into this problem with the popup

**XML code for the popup Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    style="@style/DialogTheme">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout123"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Projectlay1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Projectlay1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/tasks"
            android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
            android:id="@+id/allocateClients"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="51dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3">

        <TextView
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/budget_hours"
            android:textColor="@color/ic_launcher_background"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Billing Rate"
            android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="262dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout4">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/startdate"
            android:layout_width="314dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hours"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            tools:targetApi="o" />

        <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
            android:id="@+id/ratesspin"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="51dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loghourbtn"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:text="@string/add_staff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout7" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Logo"
        android:layout_width="303dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/smartpractice_logo_02" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="103dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout5">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Member Budget"
            android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/projectDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:hint="@string/description"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Projectlay1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="89dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/Logo">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Staff Member"
            android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
            android:id="@+id/ProjectSpinner"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="51dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Code for Popup**

```
package com.smartpractice.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.RetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class popupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> ClientName;
    ArrayList<String> UserRate;
    Spinner ClientSpinner;
    String Client;
    String ClientURL;
    String email;
    String clientId;
    String pwd;
    ImageView logo;
    String LogoUrl;
    Spinner UserRatesSpinner;
    String RatesURL;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_popup);

        ClientSpinner=findViewById(R.id.allocateClients);

        ClientName=new ArrayList<>();
        UserRate = new ArrayList<>();
        UserRatesSpinner = findViewById(R.id.ratesspin);

        logo=findViewById(R.id.Logo);
        email=getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("name", "");
        clientId=getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("id", "");
        pwd=getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("password", "");


        ClientSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")

            @Override

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                if (position == 0) {


                }

                else{


                    Client=ClientSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                }

            }

            @Override

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }

        });
        Uri.Builder ClientURLBuilder=new Uri.Builder();
        ClientURLBuilder.scheme("https")
                .authority("www.TEST.co.za")
                .appendPath("app-clients.asp")
                .appendQueryParameter("MyForm", "Yes")
                .appendQueryParameter("ClientID", clientId)
                .appendQueryParameter("Username", email)
                .appendQueryParameter("Pwd", pwd)
                .appendQueryParameter("LogType","I");
        ClientURL=ClientURLBuilder.build().toString();

        Uri.Builder LogoUrlBuilder=new Uri.Builder();
        LogoUrlBuilder.scheme("https")
                .authority("www.TEST.co.za")
                .appendPath("images")
                .appendPath("logos")
                .appendPath(clientId)
                .appendPath("main-dashboard-logo.png");

        LogoUrl=LogoUrlBuilder.build().toString();
        Uri.Builder UserRatesUrlSpinner=new Uri.Builder();
        UserRatesUrlSpinner.scheme("https")
                .authority("www.TEST.co.za")
                .appendPath("app-user-rates.asp")
                .appendQueryParameter("MyForm", "Yes")
                .appendQueryParameter("ClientID", clientId)
                .appendQueryParameter("Username", email)
                .appendQueryParameter("Pwd", pwd);
        RatesURL=UserRatesUrlSpinner.build().toString();
        Picasso.get().load(LogoUrl).into(logo);

        loadClientSpinner(ClientURL);
        loadUserRatesSpinner(RatesURL);

    }
    private void loadUserRatesSpinner(String url) {
        final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(popupActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Please Wait..Loading Time Log Data");
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        pd.show();

        RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                pd.cancel();

                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);

                    if (jsonObject.getInt("success") == 1) {

                        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("Name");

                        for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String rates=jsonObject1.getString("UserRate");



                            for(int p=0; p < 100; p++){

                                final Matcher matcher=Pattern.compile(" - ").matcher(rates);

                                if (matcher.find()) {

                                    rates =rates.substring(matcher.end()).trim();

                                }
                            }

                            UserRate.add(rates);

                        }
                    }

                    UserRatesSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(popupActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, UserRate));

                }

                catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override

            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                pd.cancel();

                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        int socketTimeout=30000;

        RetryPolicy policy=new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    private void loadClientSpinner(String url) {

        final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(popupActivity.this);

        pd.setMessage("Please Wait..Loading Project Data");

        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        pd.show();

        RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                pd.cancel();

                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);

                    if (jsonObject.getInt("success") == 1) {

                        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("Name");

                        for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String clientName=jsonObject1.getString("ClientName");

                            ClientName.add(clientName);

                        }

                    }

                    ClientSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(popupActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, ClientName));

                }

                catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override

            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                pd.cancel();

                error.printStackTrace();

            }

        });

        int socketTimeout=30000;

        RetryPolicy policy=new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

**Code for Calling Popup**

```
public  void DialogBuilder(){
     Intent GoToReport=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), popupActivity.class);
     startActivity(GoToReport);
     Animatoo.animateCard(createProject.this);

 }
```

**Manifest Entry for Popup**

```
  <activity android:name=".popupActivity"
            android:theme="@style/DialogTheme"
            />
```

**style code for DialogTheme above, Please see parent is Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert **

```
   <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert" >
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
         <item name="android:textColor">@color/Black</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Before Changing BG and Text Color
[image: Before Changing back ground and text colors]
After Changing BG and Text Color
[image: After Background and text color change]

As you can see in the screenshots that the searchbar disappears

I have fixed the hint text problem mentioned above**

Comment: what u want background white and text black??

Comment: I have the background white and text black, The problem is that my search bars and hint texts are invisible if i have the background set to white as their text is white althought I have set text to black

Comment: can you please provide screenshot of popup as it will be very clear for us to resolve your issue

Comment: so that means u hv stated search nd hint color to black but its not working! is it?

Comment: @Ajeett I have added Screenshots to show my problem

Comment: @PrajwalW, Yes I have see the screenshots to see what the problem is

Comment: provide this library to add in gradle pls - com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner

Comment: implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'       Here is the implementation for the gradle, please not that this spinner is within a Popup

Comment: paste your java code as well pls. You havent pasted the entire code as well to re-create the actual scenario.

Comment: U havent also added the pop up dialog code as well. The code u added is the layout of your screen and not the actual pop up that u have shown in the ss.

Comment: @PrajwalW Made the edits you asked for

Comment: what is the layout.xml file name that u hv pasted the code for ...the very first code in the question which contains the constraintlayout ?

Comment: @PrajwalW it is called activity_popup.xml

Comment: Pls refer my answer! u will understand the issue with your code. You need to make changes to the library itself. Refer my ans pls! accept if useful so that others may know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

From your code it is seen that:

> You are using an external library for Searchable Spinner in your
>   layout. Due to this, you wont see the spinner when background is white
>   because the library itself has spinner stated to white.

**In order to solve this issue:**

1. avoid using the library (OR)
2. make changes into the library if its owned by you or request for the same.

**The issue in code:**

```
<com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
            android:id="@+id/ProjectSpinner"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="51dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="24dp" />
```